# CSS - Possible to animate "clip" on an image to reveal quadrants clockwise?

Tags: css

I have two circular images. The top image is positioned absolutely on top of the bottom image. I am revealing the top image in 25% intervals using [clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) and I am wondering if it possible to animate it so that the quadrant gradually increases the angle like a clock. Currently I have the animation working, but the way it reveals is just straight down instead of the angle gradually increasing.

I am also open to other solutions that don't involve `clip`.

**EDIT**: I also just realized that there's no way to do the 3/4 circle using this method I am using, though I suppose I could just add another absolutely position image and have one be 180deg vertical and the other 180deg horizontal to accomplish that.

```css
.image-container {
  position:relative;
  height:180px;
  width:180px;
  border-radius:180px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
  .image-container img {
    max-width:100%;
  }
    .image-container img.top-image {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      clip: rect(0, 90px, 90px, 0);
      transform:rotate(90deg);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    }
    .image-container:hover img.top-image {
      clip: rect(0, 180px, 90px, 0);
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png"/>
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Just an observation, clip has been superceded by clip-path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a 'ticking' effect like the hand on an analogue clock you can use CSS mask with a conic gradient which will gradually reveal the underneath image.

This snippet creates a CSS animation (using JS as I was too lazy to type it all in) with 60 animation points, changing the conic gradient by 6 degrees each time. It adds the animation to the top image on hover.

```js
// create the 60 part animation
let keyframes = '@keyframes tickround {';
for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
  keyframes += i * 100 / 60 + '% {-webkit-mask-image: conic-gradient(transparent ' + 6 * i + 'deg ' + 6 * (i + 1) + 'deg, black ' + 6 * (i + 1) + 'deg 360deg); mask-image: conic-gradient(transparent ' + 6 * i + 'deg ' + 6 * (i + 1) + 'deg, black ' + 6 * (i + 1) + 'deg 360deg);}';
}
keyframes += '}';
const newstyle = document.createElement('style');
newstyle.innerHTML = keyframes;
document.head.appendChild(newstyle);
```

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-container img.top-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
  mask-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}

.image-container img.top-image:hover {
  animation: tickround 60s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png" />
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

clip-path can do it:

```css
.image-container {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  display:grid;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  grid-area:1/1;
}
/* the 400% is an arbitrary big value*/
.image-container img.top-image {
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,400% 0,400% 50%,400% 50%,50% 50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.image-container:hover img.top-image {
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,400% 0,400% 50%,50% 400%,50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png" />
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>
```

To understand what is happening add some box-shadow:

```css
.image-container {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  display:grid;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  grid-area:1/1;
}
/* the 400% is an arbitrary big value*/
.image-container img.top-image {
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,400% 0,400% 50%,400% 50%,50% 50%);
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px red;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.image-container:hover img.top-image {
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,400% 0,400% 50%,50% 400%,50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png" />
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>
```